# Vuforia with JPCT-AE error

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I had download project from https://github.com/fishkingsin/QCAR-JPCT-AE

Set all environment variable and build method that describe to build vuforia android project.
Read all blogs from vuforia sites:

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-2-installing-vuforia-sdk

Following error display in Log cat:

**Logcat  Error:**

```
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.guruonline.vuforia.jpct.ImageTargets.getOpenGlEsVersionNative:()I
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at com.guruonline.vuforia.jpct.ImageTargets.getOpenGlEsVersionNative(Native Method)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at com.guruonline.vuforia.jpct.ImageTargets.getInitializationFlags(ImageTargets.java:384)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at com.guruonline.vuforia.jpct.ImageTargets.onCreate(ImageTargets.java:355)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-08 15:00:05.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3943):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Command window error:

```
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi] Compile++ arm  : ImageTargets <= ImageTargets.cpp
jni/ImageTargets.cpp:33:34: fatal error: QCAR/TrackableResult.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/ImageTargets/ImageTargets.o] Error 1
```

Please help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download latest vuforia.jar and build project.